# IBM worklight not available in Eclipse Mars

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

I have Eclipse Mars installed (4.5.1) and IBM Mobile First studio from Eclipse Market Place. But I'm not able to find Worklight Project under New --> Other Project Option as stated in multiple articles available. Is there anything I;m missing ?
Please help
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MobileFirst Foundation 8.0 plug-in for Eclipse once recently released, replacing the plug-in for v7.1. The two plug-ins are very much different.

In v8.0 you no longer use Studio to create "projects" to create Hybrid apps, rather you use the Cordova CLI to create a Cordova app, and also use the Cordova CLI to add the MobileFirst SDK (plug-in) to the Cordova app.

The Studio plug-in for Eclipse in v8.0 is used to expose functionality provided by the MobileFirst CLI (register app, open console, and so on...), and so it will work only if you will also have the MobileFirst CLI installed, as well as the THyM plug-in for Eclipse, which makes Eclipse into a dev environment for Cordova apps.

If you're looking for Studio 7.1 plug-in, you can [download it from here](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/downloads/)

Learn more about v8.0, here:

- https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/06/17/ibm-releases-next-generation-of-mobilefirst-foundation-built-for-hybrid-cloud/
- https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/using-the-mfpf-sdk/using-mobilefirst-cli-in-eclipse/
- https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/06/17/migrating-apps-and-adapters-to-mobilefirst-foundation-8-0/